# Puzzle with PHP using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a problem using codeigniter, now I have a system that show you a question in a page called start, the question comes random from the database using this code.

```
$data['question'] = $this->Setting->Loop('challenges_questions', 'ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1');
```

then check the form_validation

```
if($this->form_validation->run() === TRUE){
    foreach($data['question']->result() as $ques){
        $query = $this->Challenges_Model->addAnswer($ques->the_answer);
    }
}
```

this is the model

```
public function addAnswer($answer){
    if($this->input->post('answer') == $answer){
        if(!$this->session->userdata('is_stopped')){
            $this->db->query("UPDATE challenges_scores SET points = points+1 WHERE user_id = ".$this->session->userdata('id').";");
            //$this->db->set('points' , 'points+1');
            //$this->db->where('user_id', $this->session->userdata('id'));
            //$this->db->update('challenges_scores');
        }else{
            // unSet
            $this->session->unset_userdata('is_stopped');
        }
        return TRUE;
    }else{
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

now my problem is when the user post the input (the answer), the query is refreshed, then the answer is changed then the form input answer is wrong.

is there any way to save data to use it after the post ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic is the same as an update form:

Model:

```
function get() {
    return $this->db->get('sometable')->result();
}
```

Controller:

```
function index() {
   $data['result'] = $this->sommodel->get();
   $this->load->view('someview', $data);
}
```

Here we get the post value if there is any (in case of bad form validation submit) and if not we have the value from the db

```
<input name="somefield" value="<?php isset($_POST['somefield']) { echo $_POST['somefield'] } else { echo $result->somefield; } ?>">
```

If it's just one thing just store it in a session variable and do the same logic by instead of `$result->somefield` you put `$this->session->somefield`. I wouldn't recommend this approach if it's alot of data.

Comment: Thanks very much, and I found an other solution, by adding a hidden input has a value of question id then at the background check the answer.

Comment: Whatever methods works for you. This is just one way of doing things.